# How to offset/ move Key Numbering and its lists instead of covering line features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

Does anyone know how to move the placement of the key numbers and the key numbering lists?

I am labeling lines and the key number keeps getting placed on the line. But if the line is very small, the key number covers the line rather than labels offset from the line. I also Can't figure to move the list around. It would be nice if I could move that list to a standard position (i.e. on a legend).

Comment: also if i have a halo around my label, the list needs to be spaced. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to offset Key Numbers go to the Labels tab in the layer Properties window. Under the Text Symbols section click Symbol this opens the symbol selector window then select Edit Symbol. In the properties sections under the General Tab you can set the x y Offset this will apply to all labels including those that use Key Numbers.